# How to do grid search on multiple groups in the data?

Tags: r, tidyverse

### Data and Goal

My dataset has multiple groups. Following is a simple reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  participant = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 7)),
  Time = c(1:5, 1:7),
  x = c(rnorm(5, 0, 1), rnorm(7, 0, 10)),
  y = (0.5 * x) + (0.7 * x)
)
```

Here I have 2 participants (`A` and `B`), and also have `x` and `y` variables recorded for both participants.

I want to estimate `y_hat` based on a custom function as shown below:

```
find_y_hat <- function(participant_data, param1, param2){
  
  participant_data %>% 
    mutate(y_hat = (param1 * x) + (param2 * x))
}
```

#### Example:

If I provide values for `param1` and `param2`, I get the following result for participant `A`:

```
participant_A_data <- df %>% 
  filter(participant == "A")

find_y_hat(participant_A_data, 
           param1 = 0, param2 = 0.5)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  participant  Time      x      y   y_hat
  <chr>       <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A               1 -0.336 -0.404 -0.168 
2 A               2  1.24   1.49   0.619 
3 A               3  0.520  0.624  0.260 
4 A               4 -0.438 -0.525 -0.219 
5 A               5  0.122  0.147  0.0612
```

My goal here is to apply this function using several different values of both parameters for each participant. So, I have the following parameter grid:

```
paramz_grid <- expand.grid(
  param1 = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7),
  param2 = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
)
paramz_grid
param1 param2
1     0.0    0.0
2     0.5    0.0
3     0.6    0.0
4     0.7    0.0
5     0.0    0.5
6     0.5    0.5
7     0.6    0.5
8     0.7    0.5
9     0.0    0.6
10    0.5    0.6
11    0.6    0.6
12    0.7    0.6
13    0.0    0.7
14    0.5    0.7
15    0.6    0.7
16    0.7    0.7
```

### What I tried to do

I figured that I could use the nesting and `purrr::map` functions to achieve the goal. But I do not know how to combine the inputs from each participant (total = 2) and each parameter combination (total = 16). I think `pmap` could be used but I can't figure out how to use it.  Please guide me.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(participant) %>% 
   group_nest()
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  participant           data
* <chr>       <list<tibble>>
1 A                  [5 x 3]
2 B                  [7 x 3]
```

#### EDIT

I have tried the following, but was unsuccessful:

```
paramz_grid <- paramz_grid %>% 
  rowid_to_column()

l1 <- paramz_grid %>% 
  split(.$rowid)


l2 <- df %>% 
  split(.$participant)



pmap(.l = list(l1, l2, rowz = 1:nrow(paramz_grid)),
     .f = ~find_y_hat(participant_data = l2,
                     l1[[rowz]]$param1,  l1[[rowz]]$param2))

Error: Element 2 of `.l` must have length 1 or 16, not 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the output you want, but I can get something close if I change the function a bit to just use vectors - e.g. `y_hat_new <- function(x, param1, param2) {
    (param1 * x) + (param2 * x)
}` and then apply it to get 16x2 results `df %>%
    group_by(participant) %>%
    summarise(out = pmap(list(list(x), paramz_grid$param1, paramz_grid$param2), y_hat_new) )` - would that work okay for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `purrr::pmap()`, or even `purrr::pmap_dfr()`:

```r
setseed(1)
#...
x = paramz_grid %>% pmap(~{    
    df %>% 
        group_by(participant) %>% 
        mutate(param1=.x, param2=.y) %>% 
        find_y_hat(param1=.x, param2=.y)
})


x[[7]]
#> # A tibble: 12 x 7
#> # Groups:   participant [2]
#>    participant  Time       x       y param1 param2   y_hat
#>    <chr>       <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 A               1  -1.24   -1.49     0.6    0.5  -1.36 
#>  2 A               2  -0.702  -0.842    0.6    0.5  -0.772
#>  3 A               3   0.103   0.124    0.6    0.5   0.114
#>  4 A               4  -1.46   -1.75     0.6    0.5  -1.60 
#>  5 A               5   0.969   1.16     0.6    0.5   1.07 
#>  6 B               1   6.03    7.24     0.6    0.5   6.64 
#>  7 B               2 -11.1   -13.3      0.6    0.5 -12.2  
#>  8 B               3   7.56    9.07     0.6    0.5   8.32 
#>  9 B               4 -12.5   -15.0      0.6    0.5 -13.8  
#> 10 B               5 -12.3   -14.8      0.6    0.5 -13.5  
#> 11 B               6  24.7    29.6      0.6    0.5  27.2  
#> 12 B               7   2.02    2.42     0.6    0.5   2.22
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I wanted to add the params in the results as columns and this solution provides that. Thank you. I didn't know that I could group inside `pmap`.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are probably looking for a `tidyverse` solution, but as an alternative I could offer you this `data.table` approach:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(
    participant = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 7)),
    Time = c(1:5, 1:7),
    x = c(rnorm(5, 0, 1), rnorm(7, 0, 10)))[
        , y := (0.5 * x) + (0.7 * x)]

paramz_grid <- expand.grid(
    param1 = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7),
    param2 = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
)

df[, paste0("y_hat: ", apply(paramz_grid,1,paste, collapse=",")):=
       lapply(seq_len(nrow(paramz_grid)), 
              function(z) (paramz_grid[z,1] * x) + (paramz_grid[z,2] * x)), 
   by=participant][]
#>     participant Time            x            y y_hat: 0,0 y_hat: 0.5,0
#>  1:           A    1  -0.56047565  -0.67257078          0  -0.28023782
#>  2:           A    2  -0.23017749  -0.27621299          0  -0.11508874
#>  3:           A    3   1.55870831   1.87044998          0   0.77935416
#>  4:           A    4   0.07050839   0.08461007          0   0.03525420
#>  5:           A    5   0.12928774   0.15514528          0   0.06464387
#>  6:           B    1  17.15064987  20.58077984          0   8.57532493
#>  7:           B    2   4.60916206   5.53099447          0   2.30458103
#>  8:           B    3 -12.65061235 -15.18073482          0  -6.32530617
#>  9:           B    4  -6.86852852  -8.24223422          0  -3.43426426
#> 10:           B    5  -4.45661970  -5.34794364          0  -2.22830985
#> 11:           B    6  12.24081797  14.68898157          0   6.12040899
#> 12:           B    7   3.59813827   4.31776592          0   1.79906914
#>     y_hat: 0.6,0 y_hat: 0.7,0 y_hat: 0,0.5 y_hat: 0.5,0.5 y_hat: 0.6,0.5
#>  1:  -0.33628539  -0.39233295  -0.28023782    -0.56047565    -0.61652321
#>  2:  -0.13810649  -0.16112424  -0.11508874    -0.23017749    -0.25319524
#>  3:   0.93522499   1.09109582   0.77935416     1.55870831     1.71457915
#>  4:   0.04230503   0.04935587   0.03525420     0.07050839     0.07755923
#>  5:   0.07757264   0.09050141   0.06464387     0.12928774     0.14221651
#>  6:  10.29038992  12.00545491   8.57532493    17.15064987    18.86571486
#>  7:   2.76549724   3.22641344   2.30458103     4.60916206     5.07007827
#>  8:  -7.59036741  -8.85542864  -6.32530617   -12.65061235   -13.91567358
#>  9:  -4.12111711  -4.80796996  -3.43426426    -6.86852852    -7.55538137
#> 10:  -2.67397182  -3.11963379  -2.22830985    -4.45661970    -4.90228167
#> 11:   7.34449078   8.56857258   6.12040899    12.24081797    13.46489977
#> 12:   2.15888296   2.51869679   1.79906914     3.59813827     3.95795210
#>     y_hat: 0.7,0.5 y_hat: 0,0.6 y_hat: 0.5,0.6 y_hat: 0.6,0.6 y_hat: 0.7,0.6
#>  1:    -0.67257078  -0.33628539    -0.61652321    -0.67257078    -0.72861834
#>  2:    -0.27621299  -0.13810649    -0.25319524    -0.27621299    -0.29923074
#>  3:     1.87044998   0.93522499     1.71457915     1.87044998     2.02632081
#>  4:     0.08461007   0.04230503     0.07755923     0.08461007     0.09166091
#>  5:     0.15514528   0.07757264     0.14221651     0.15514528     0.16807406
#>  6:    20.58077984  10.29038992    18.86571486    20.58077984    22.29584483
#>  7:     5.53099447   2.76549724     5.07007827     5.53099447     5.99191068
#>  8:   -15.18073482  -7.59036741   -13.91567358   -15.18073482   -16.44579605
#>  9:    -8.24223422  -4.12111711    -7.55538137    -8.24223422    -8.92908707
#> 10:    -5.34794364  -2.67397182    -4.90228167    -5.34794364    -5.79360561
#> 11:    14.68898157   7.34449078    13.46489977    14.68898157    15.91306337
#> 12:     4.31776592   2.15888296     3.95795210     4.31776592     4.67757975
#>     y_hat: 0,0.7 y_hat: 0.5,0.7 y_hat: 0.6,0.7 y_hat: 0.7,0.7
#>  1:  -0.39233295    -0.67257078    -0.72861834    -0.78466591
#>  2:  -0.16112424    -0.27621299    -0.29923074    -0.32224849
#>  3:   1.09109582     1.87044998     2.02632081     2.18219164
#>  4:   0.04935587     0.08461007     0.09166091     0.09871175
#>  5:   0.09050141     0.15514528     0.16807406     0.18100283
#>  6:  12.00545491    20.58077984    22.29584483    24.01090982
#>  7:   3.22641344     5.53099447     5.99191068     6.45282688
#>  8:  -8.85542864   -15.18073482   -16.44579605   -17.71085728
#>  9:  -4.80796996    -8.24223422    -8.92908707    -9.61593993
#> 10:  -3.11963379    -5.34794364    -5.79360561    -6.23926758
#> 11:   8.56857258    14.68898157    15.91306337    17.13714516
#> 12:   2.51869679     4.31776592     4.67757975     5.03739358
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

If you prefer keeping `y_hat` as a list column, you could modify the operation above with

```r
df[, y_hat:=list(.(lapply(seq_len(nrow(paramz_grid)), 
              function(z) (paramz_grid[z,1] * x) + (paramz_grid[z,2] * x)))), 
   by=participant][]
``
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x) {
    map2_df(paramz_grid$param1, paramz_grid$param2, 
           ~find_y_hat(x, param1 = .x, param2 = .y))
  })) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest(data)

# A tibble: 192 x 5
#   participant  Time       x       y   y_hat
#   <chr>       <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A               1 -0.776  -0.932   0     
# 2 A               2 -0.0680 -0.0816  0     
# 3 A               3 -0.160  -0.192   0     
# 4 A               4 -0.487  -0.584   0     
# 5 A               5  2.50    3.01    0     
# 6 A               1 -0.776  -0.932  -0.388 
# 7 A               2 -0.0680 -0.0816 -0.0340
# 8 A               3 -0.160  -0.192  -0.0798
# 9 A               4 -0.487  -0.584  -0.243 
#10 A               5  2.50    3.01    1.25  
# … with 182 more rows
```

For multiple arguments in `paramz_grid` use `pmap_df` and call the function with `do.call`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x) {
    pmap_df(paramz_grid, ~{
      val <- c(...)
      do.call(find_y_hat, c(participant_data = list(x), as.list(val)))
    })
  })) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest(data)
```

For every `participant`, `map2_df` creates a combined dataframe of `param1` and `param2` values.

Comment: Thanks. I need `pmap`, as my original data has 10 parameters. I tried replacing your code with `pmap` but I get the error that the input list has unequal length objects.

Comment: I updated the answer to use it with `pmap_df`,  maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.